# How to add HTML markup and CSS style in PHP

Tags: php, css, woocommerce

I'm not versed in PHP. I've been trying to add css to the following php snippet but to no avail.

```
add_filter(  'gettext',  'change_related_products_title', 10, 3 );
function change_related_products_title( $translated, $text, $domain  ) {
    if( $text === 'Related products' && $domain === 'woocommerce' ){
        $translated = esc_html__( 'These go well with', $domain ) . ' ' . esc_html( get_the_title() );
    }
    return $translated;
}
```

As far as I understand, `echo` works but it returns errors with the snippet. `printf` is closer to the result I want to achieve but it adds a random number which I have no idea what it represents.

Below is what I have attempted:

```
add_filter(  'gettext',  'change_related_products_title', 10, 3 );
function change_related_products_title( $translated, $text, $domain  ) {
    if( $text === 'Related products' && $domain === 'woocommerce' ){
        $css = '<h1>Some Text</h1>';
        $translated = printf($css , $domain ) . ' ' . esc_html( get_the_title() );
    }
    return $translated;
}
```

The above snippet returns: Some Text *random number* title.

The actual result I am trying to achieve is to have the output wrapped with css tag for styling purpose. For e.g. Like this:

**Some Text** *title*

Comment: What error message do you get when you use `echo`? Also, `<h1>Some Text</h1>` is HTML, not CSS. In any case, why not just `return "<h1>$translated</h1>";`?

Comment: I don’t see CSS in your code. Could you rephrase to describe in more detail what you want the output to be. Also if you are getting errors show them in your question,

Comment: @kmoser Thanks. -_-" I reckon that's the problem with self learning at the beginning stage. Confuse and didn't make an effort to get the terms right.  Thanks for pointing out is HTML markup. `return "<h1>$translated</h1>"` returns it as a text string which is not what I want to. I want to style it.

Comment: @AHaworth Sorry, as kmoser has pointed out, is HTML markup. It doesn't have specific error message but the whole site is broken.

Comment: @jollysea You don't seem to understand how CSS works in relation to HTML. The simple (but not best) way to do what you want would be `$translated = '<span style="font-weight:bold;">' . $domain . '</span> <span style="font-style:italic;">' . esc_html( get_the_title() ) . '</span>';`. The better way would be to emit class names rather than inline CSS, and style those class names in an external style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

1. That was not the random number, it is the count of the characters in $css.
2. The printf requires % identifier. Please refer to [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)
3. The html h1 is a block level element which will not display inline block with your title as your expected result. So you need to write your custom css to display it in-line block.

Hope below code will get you the required output

```
$css = '<div class="wrapping-class"><div class="custom-class">Some Text</div>%s</div>';

printf($css,  esc_html( get_the_title() ));
```

Generated HTML Tags

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to stop the character count from showing?